# Calling a GET variable in a POST function

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to add the $item_id into the 'bid' table after clicking on the button.
But the $item_id from the $_GET cannot be passed into the $_POST function.
Is it incorrect to call a variable like this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<?php 
include ('config/dbfunctions.php'); 
include ("helpers/validateBid.php");

$user_id = "";
$item_id = "";
$table= 'bid';
$allBids = selectAll($table);
$items = selectAll('item');

if (isset($_GET['item_id'])) {
    $itemInfoPost  = selectOne('item', ['item_id' => $_GET['item_id']]);
    $item_id = $itemInfoPost['item_id'];
  } 
  

if(isset($_POST['bid-btn'])){
  
        unset($_POST['bid-btn']);
        $_POST['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $_POST['item_id'] = $item_id;   //$item_id cannot be called
        $bid_id = create($table, $_POST);   
              
        header('location: itemInfo.php?item_id='."$item_id"); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
      <form action="itemInfo.php" method="post">
        <div class="place-bid-form">
          <h6>Place your bid</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="place-bid-form-container">
          <div class="bidamount-icon">RM</div>
          <input class="placebidInput"  type="number" name="bid_amount">
        </div>

        <div class="place-bid-form">
          <button type="submit" name="bid-btn" class="btn bid-btn">Bid Now</button>
         
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: what is your form method ?

Comment: @AqibJaved I'm using post

Comment: var_dump($_POST) and check all the variables being posted. Alos check 'item_id' is there or not

Comment: you can add a hidden field in the form with the item_id value if you want to have it in $_POST. But also in the query string is a valid option.

Comment: Its really not clear how you have called this code from a form! But in this code, `$item_id` will only ever even EXIST if `isset($_GET['item_id'])` BUT if it does not EXISTS you still try and USE IT IN `$_POST['item_id'] = $item_id;` So reviewing your logic here would do no harm

Comment: We cannot help much unless you show us your code for the page that calls this script

Comment: thanks y'all for the advice too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the action attribute of your form has the item id like this:

```html
<form id="mybidform" action="itemInfo.php?item_id=123456" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

or you can set the item id dynamically via JavaScript/jQuery like this before you submit your form:

```js
$('button[name="bid-btn"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let actionWithItemId = $("#mybidform").prop("action") + "?item_id=" + 123456;
    $("#mybidform").prop("action", actionWithItemId).submit();

});

If you don't use jQuery, I would post plain Javascript code also.
```

Comment: it really is because of the form's action attribute! After adding it, i was able to pass the value thank you! :)